# JavaScript: Regex date format

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to create a regex that does a format on a sting of digits.

I'm new to regex and this is as far I got.

```
function keyEvents(target) {
    var element = document.getElementById(target);

    element.addEventListener('keyup', function(evt) {
        if (isNaN(this.value) || (evt.keyCode === 70)) {
             this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
        };
    });
};

keyEvents('dateInput');
```

When I introduce a string like '12112001' I would like it to be formatted like so '12/11/2001'.

Is it possible to do that only with regex?

This a link to JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w7fduzx3/1/

Comment: Why regex? Substring will do here.

Comment: `<input type="date">` <- Done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one will work:

```
"12112001".replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/, "$1/$2/$3");
```

By using parentheses in Regexp you can define matching groups and then access them via `$<number>` operator. Regular expression above simply splits number string into three groups:

2 digits - 2 digits - 4 digits and "joins" them with `/`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution without regex using `substr()` (slightly faster):

```
var date  = '12112001';
date = date.substr(0,2)+'/'+date.substr(2,2)+'/'+date.substr(4,4);
```